# RPC/Encoded WSDL's GenerateWSDL

Tags: apex, soap

I'm trying to generate a apex class from WSDL actually i am importing some Web Services which are in the ***RPC/Encoded*** style.

i am having this issue while generate apex code from WSDL

Error : `Unsupported WSDL style 'rpc'. Only supports Dcoument/literal/wrapped services.`

Is it possible to develop Apex Code by hand which will talk with these Web Services? Some how i really want to create this class, if you have any suggestion would be helpful for me, thanks in Advance